# Free Cadastral Map

Tags: geospatial, city

I'm writing a theoretical paper on landscape planning. I need a cadastral map to illustrate some things. It could be a map of a real city (doesn't matter in which country or state) or a fictional one (doesn't matter as long as the map is precise and if possible covers a whole city).

The filetype of the map doesn't matter (dwg,shp,svg,tif etc.).

Comment: what about for a state?

Comment: Thank you @daniel-miller and albert. I didn't know cadastral data was publicly available in the US (in Germany it is not :/ ). The cadastre for Greater Geelong looks very interesting. I think that perfectly fits my needs! :)

Comment: @jan-doggen my question includes **fictional** cities, so it should have been clear that the country doesn't matter. Updated the question anyways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

> A Cadastre is normally a parcel based, and up-to-date land information
>   system containing a record of interests in land (e.g. rights,
>   restrictions and responsibilities). It usually includes a geometric
>   description of land parcels linked to other records describing the
>   nature of the interests, the ownership or control of those interests,
>   and often the value of the parcel and its improvements.

Cadastral maps or parcel data can be found across the United States. Any county property appraiser will be able to provide you with this data and can be combined to form a basic city or metropolitan area.

Statewide Data in Shapefile Formats

- Alabama: [Site with County List](http://gis.alabama.gov/Browse.aspx)
- Alaska: [Site with Borough List](http://www.asgdc.state.ak.us//#2906)
- California: [Entire State, scroll down to parcel_data.zip](ftp://data.scag.ca.gov/)
- Florida: [FTP Link for 2012 Parcel Data;](ftp://ftp.fgdl.org/pub/state/parcels_2012.zip) newer would at county level
- Montana Cadastral: [Site](http://svc.mt.gov/msl/mtcadastral/) / [FTP link for Parcel Data](ftp://ftp.geoinfo.msl.mt.gov/Data/Spatial/MSDI/Cadastral/)
- New York: [Parcels available for state and county](http://gis.ny.gov/gisdata/inventories/details.cfm?DSID=1300)
- Utah: [County Level](https://gis.utah.gov/data/sgid-cadastre/parcels/)

Answer (score 5):

[Greater Geelong, Australia's Cadastral GIS Data](https://data.gov.au/dataset/cadastre-land-and-property-boundaries-city-of-greater-geelong)
and here is [Montana's Cadastral Map/Data](http://svc.mt.gov/msl/mtcadastral/) if state level is not too big for your example.